# Nexe module Command 'nexe' not found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, executable, nexe

I have tried to run

```sh
nexe --help
```

or

```sh
nexe index.js
```

but it has returned this error:

```sh
Command 'nexe' not found, did you mean:

  command 'rexe' from snap rexe (0.7)
  command 'next' from deb mailutils-mh (1:3.7-2.1)
  command 'next' from deb mmh (0.4-2)
  command 'next' from deb nmh (1.7.1-6)
  command 'nex' from deb nvi (1.81.6-15build1)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

I am using an *Ubuntu* system. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

- First, uninstall the nexe module installed on the system locally and remove it from `package.json` using:

```sh
npm uninstall nexe -S
```

or if it is a dev dependency, use:

```sh
npm uninstall nexe -D -S
```

If you installed it globally, use:

```sh
npm uninstall nexe -g
```

- Now install the package using the `sudo` command as a global package:

```sh
sudo npm i nexe -g
```

- Run the command again once fully installed:

```sh
nexe --help
```

If it gives out the help console output, run now:

```sh
nexe index.js
```